Spring Boot error in startup after upgrading to Java 21 from Java 8
I aam upgrading my Spring Boot application from Java 8 to Java 21 and Spring boot 2.2 to 3.2. After upgrading I am getting this error on startup
|WARN |    o.s.b.a.o.j.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration(232)     |> spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
|WARN |    o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         (288)     |> Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest,jakarta.servlet.ServletResponse,jakarta.servlet.FilterChain) throws jakarta.servlet.ServletException,java.io.IOException] because it is marked as final, consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead.
|WARN |    o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy         (288)     |> Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(jakarta.servlet.FilterConfig) throws jakarta.servlet.ServletException] because it is marked as final, consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead.
|ERROR|    o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      (175)     |> Exception starting filter [loggingFilter]
Cannot invoke "org.apache.commons.logging.Log.isDebugEnabled()" because "this.logger" is null
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3844)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4448)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:772)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:870)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:437)

I am not sure what is the issue and what is causing the NULL Pointer. Is it something to do with version mismatch of any library?

There is no solution for my issue in the duplicate question.

Run app with --debug. Do you run from IDE or from CLI?
